# ExpressJS not call ajax get method

Tags: node.js, express

I created a sample ExpressJS App by using [Express Application Generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)

I want to call localhost:3000/data to get some data. I added these code to app.js:

```
app.get('/data', function(req, res){
  debug("get data");
});
```

Also I make ajax request in client side js file :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/data/',
    //url: 'http://localhost:3000/data', -> also not work
    type:'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: (data) => {
        console.log("get data from client js", data);
    }
});
```

but my `app.get` method never call. `GET /data/ 404` written in console screen. Also when I typed http://localhost:3000/data on browser I got Not Found error. how can I fix this ?

---

my `www` file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('myapp:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;

  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: did you try testing on postman?

Comment: also can you post full server code

Comment: I updated my question. also I got 404 on postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure where your problem lies because there isn't enough code displayed to determine that. instead I have written a simple express server for you to use:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const CORS = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(CORS());


app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    res.json({message: "working"});
});


app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 5000');
});
```